# Android app crashing randomly(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

My app is constantly communicating with the network and it runs perfectly when I launch it first time.
But after sometime when I go minimize the app or switch between different apps and then when I open my app its getting crash.
Here is the log:

> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318): Process: com.aleph.view, PID: 15318
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aleph.model.MessageTypes
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at com.al+nuListActivity.prepareURL(MainMenuListActivity.java:435)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at com.aleph.view.abstractActivity.TemplateListActivity.processThread(TemplateListActivity.java:148)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at
>    com.aleph.controller.MainMenuAction.ListItemClick(MainMenuAction.java:168)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at com.aleph.view.myTrip.MainMenuListActivity.onListItemClick(MainMenuListActivity.java:109)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1186)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3099)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4046)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at
>    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872:E/AndroidRuntime(15318):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
>
> 10-19 16:53:12.872: E/AndroidRuntime(15318):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

Followed by:

> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425): Process: com.aleph.view,
>    PID: 16425
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
>   ComponentInfo{com.aleph.view/com.aleph.view.myTrip.LoginActivity}: 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425): Caused by:
>    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>    'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at com.aleph.model.phoneHome.PhoneHomeValidator.checkMobileData(PhoneHomeValidator.java:124)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at com.aleph.model.phoneHome.PhoneHomeValidator.primeMobileForValidation(PhoneHomeValidator.java:54)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    com.aleph.view.myTrip.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:70)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  at
>    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>
> 10-19 16:54:08.802: E/AndroidRuntime(16425):  ... 10 more

trying to solve this since long time. please help

Comment: Did you check what is Null ?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aleph.model.MessageTypes, is this your class?, is it deployed.. it can't find it...

Comment: post your code also.

Comment: Its difficult to figure out what the problem is with the information you have provided. Do you have any code in your onPause or onStop? 
You should be very aware of the Android life cycle, especially if you are doing lots of network communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to do:

• Add the following lines to your proguard config file (usually called proguard-android.txt or proguard-rules.pro):

```
-keep class MessageTypes

-keep class com.aleph.model.MessageTypes
```

• Refresh your build

• Build the app again

Let me know if this worked, if not, I'll look further into it.

Comment: It didn't work. let me know if you need more information to solve. Also its getting crash when I open the app for first time then kill it with task killer and again open it throws the  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aleph.model.MessageTypes

Answer (score 1):

Is this from a Samsung device?  I think Samsung is too aggressive with their native code compiler optimizations or something.  I use Splunk MINT to receive remote stack traces, and there are three kinds of crashes that I see on Samsung devices in like one out of every few thousand runs:

- Process is trying to do something as user -2
- App doesn't have permission that it clearly does have
- Random inexplicable NoClassDefFoundError